# Why is the transition state the highest energy point?

Tags: bond, energy, transition-state-theory

If partial bonds form during transition state, it means some energy is released, so how can it have the highest energy? Shouldn't the point before transition state be highest energy? (the point where all the bonds are broken and new bonds have not started to form?) Or is it because such a point where all bonds are broken and new bonds have not started to form is non-existent, by which i mean that when the reaction takes place, bonds weaken and partially form at the same time?

Comment: Exactly. Also, that’s the definition of transition state, highest energy on the reaction coordinate.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP already knew and stated the correct explanation and merely wanted confirmation.

Comment: It would be better to consider the transition state as part of the lowest energy pathway on the change from reactant to product. The transition state itself in 3D has the appearance of a saddle, up and down through the highest point on the reaction path, but is the minimum energy at 90$^o$ to this path. Because of vibrations any particular trajectory will pass close to the minimum energy path but need not be exactly on it. Why is it the highest point is that it is the only point of no return. (btw, we 'know' transition states only from approximate theory, not so far from experiment.)